# scapy - how to display (encode hex) instead of str

Tags: python, scapy

I have below defined -

```
class PadChecksum(Packet):
    name = "PadChecksum"
    fields_desc = [ StrField("data", None) ]

conf.raw_layer = PadChecksum
```

how to display as below as ?

```
###[ PadChecksum ]###
       data      = '\x00\x00\x00\xa8L\xa8\xe5'
```

as

```
###[ PadChecksum ]###
       data      = '00 00 00 a8 4c a8 e5'
```

also how can I show it as below to be more precise ?

```
###[ PadChecksum ]###
       pad      = '00 00 00'
       checksum = 'a8 4c a8 e5'
```

Answer (score 2):

got it !!

```
class XStrField(StrField):
      def i2repr(self, pkt, x):
            return ' '.join(b.encode('hex') for b in x)

class PadChecksum(Packet):
    name = "PadChecksum"
    fields_desc = [ XStrField("data", None) ]
```

display --

```
###[ PadChecksum ]###
       data      = 00 00 00 eb 62 aa 9d
```